# Return 2 random images from an array

Tags: c#, random, unique

I'm trying to get back 2 unique images form an array. Right now I'm refreshing the page until I get 2 unique images. This is not ideal. How can I modify this code to back 2 unique images with out refreshing the page till it hapens.

Can I do it in this layer or do I need to check for unique numbers in the data layer?

```
 Picture dlPicture = new Picture();
        DataTable DTPictures = dlPicture.GetRandomPicture();
        Picture dlPicture2 = new Picture();
        DataTable DTPictures2 = dlPicture2.GetRandomPicture();



        // the variables to hold the yes and no Id's for each set
        string firstNoPicId = "";
        string firstYesPicId = "";
        string secondNoPicId = "";
        string secondYesPicId = "";

        foreach (DataRow row in DTPictures.Rows)
        {
            firstYesPicId = row["PicID"].ToString();
            secondNoPicId = firstYesPicId;
            FirstPicMemberNameLabel.Text = row["MemberName"].ToString();
            FirstPicLink.ImageUrl = "Pictures/" + row["PicLoc"];

        }

        foreach (DataRow row in DTPictures2.Rows)
        {
            secondYesPicId = row["PicID"].ToString();
            firstNoPicId = secondYesPicId;
            SecondPicMemberNameLabel.Text = row["MemberName"].ToString();
            SecondPicLink.ImageUrl = "Pictures/" + row["PicLoc"];

        }
        if (firstYesPicId != secondYesPicId)
        {

            FirstPicLink.PostBackUrl = "default.aspx?yesId=" + firstYesPicId + "&noId=" + firstNoPicId;
            SecondPicLink.PostBackUrl = "default.aspx?yesId=" + secondYesPicId + "&noId=" + secondNoPicId;
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
```

Comment: where's the code for .GetRandomPicture() ?

Comment: Why is `GetRandomPicture` returning a `DataTable` any why are you looping its rows and setting the same variables over and over again?

Comment: I don't see anything random in your code.

Comment: Sorry I wanted to see if i could acomplish it in this layer not the datalayer. If the responses below dont soleve the issue ill provide the code in the DL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a better solution would be adding code to your datalayer.GetRandomPicture to make sure it can't return the same picture twice in a row?

in this Picture class add a LastRandomPictureID variable and do a 'WHERE NOT ID = LastRandomPictureID' on your query (you might want to make it a bit more robust to handle the case where only 1 picture exists).

Comment: Your right i know thats the cleanest and correct way. I jstu wanted to see if i coudl accomplish it in this layer instead. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There two pretty obvious ways to deal with this

1. Add an overload  `dlPicture.GetRandomPicture(int picID)` This will accept an ID so that it won't return an already used picID
2. restructure your code so that it loops until the `secondYesPicId != firstYesPicId`

Something like

```
 secondYesPicId = firstYesPicId;
 while (firstYesPicId == secondYesPicId)
 {  DataTable DTPictures2 = dlPicture2.GetRandomPicture();

     foreach (DataRow row in DTPictures2.Rows)
    {
        secondYesPicId = row["PicID"].ToString();
        SecondPicMemberNameLabel.Text = row["MemberName"].ToString();
        SecondPicLink.ImageUrl = "Pictures/" + row["PicLoc"];

    }
 }
```

Comment: I find loops like that make me nervous about the possibilities of infinitely looping.  I Like the overload suggestion.

Comment: @MalcolmO'Hare Agreed, but you should note that the current solution is already in that state (since it redirects when it fails to find two unique results). At least this way you can add a Tries counter and give up after x # of tries

Comment: Your right about the over load method. That would be the cleanest way. I used your code above and it works great. Its not the cleanest but works. THis is the first site i ever built in Csharp or .net Im learnigin so much and getting in binds every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rnd = new Random();
int randomPicIndex1 = rnd.Next(numOfPictures);
int randomPicIndex2;
do {
    randomPicIndex2 = rnd.Next(numOfPictures);
} while (randomPicIndex1 == randomPicIndex2);
```

Then use these indexes in order to get random rows from your table.

```
DataRow row1 = DTPictures.Rows[randomPicIndex1];
DataRow row2 = DTPictures.Rows[randomPicIndex2];
```